# Nim intellisense not working properly with nim jester

Tags: intellisense, nim-lang, jester

Nim intellisense not working properly with nim jester as when i am hovering over any object or variable it is not showing any details there in the routes block.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling vscode, restarted my computer, etc but it is still not working. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Sadly there is little that can be done there at the moment.
Any tooling around intellisense is built on nim's `nimsuggest` to analyze code and find issues. Given how difficult macros are and to a degree also in general, nimsuggest has a tendency to choke on things for no reason that I've been able to particularly make out.

IntelliJ is the only thing not built on nimsuggest with its own way of parsing and following symbols, which might work better for you, but isn't 100% either. You could try that out though to see if that improves your experience.